# Quarkus DynamoDB test initialization

Tags: quarkus

How do people generally go about the task of e.g. creating a DynamoDB table against a localstack before tests and deleting it afterwards?

Apparently QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager implementations aren't CDI aware so I can't inject a DynamoDbEnhancedClient. And Arc.container().instance(DynamoDbEnhancedClient.class).get() gives null for the container so it doesn't look enabled.

I could of course create the client->enhanced client through builders but apparently application.properties aren't read because it gets created somewhere else (my default AWS credentials?) because I get "table not found" when running the test.

I could of course force the builder with the same stuff as in the application.properties but at that point I came to the conclusion that "it can probably be done in a more sane way" and that's why I'm here...

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Apparently junit lifecycle methods @Before* etc works